# Somar Quantidade e valor agrupando por Produto

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema para calcular a produção de produtos.
Eu insiro os produtos e tenho que calcular a quantidade total de Matéria prima que será utilizada.

Insiro

```
Produto 1 (5g de ouro) - 10 quantidades
Produto 2 (3g de ouro) - 5 quantidades
```

Meu cálculo aparece assim:

Matéria Prima

```
Ouro: 5 gramas * 10 = 50
Ouro: 3 gramas * 5 = 15
Pedra: 10 unidades
Diamante : 1
Diamante : 1
```

No entanto gostaria que aparecesse Agrupado:

```
Ouro Total = 65
Pedra = 10 
Diamante = 2
```

Agradeço desde já.

Meu código

```
<?php
  $query = "select material.*,  producao.*  from material LEFT JOIN producao  
  ON material.id_prod = producao.id_prod WHERE producao.id_producao ='$id'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $material = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
                    $qtd = $row['qtd'];
                    $qtde = $row['qtde'];
                    $qtdTotal = $qtd * $qtde;
                }           
}
?>
```

Comment: Teria como atualizar a pergunta com as colunas da tabela `materal` e `producao`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para resolver seu problema é só usar o [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) do sql para agrupar pelo nome do material, e depois fazer o calculo que quer, tentei fazer todo o somatório dentro e multiplicação dentro do SQL.

Abaixo segue o código:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT 
  material.nome, (SUM(producao.qtd) * SUM(producao.qtde)) AS total
FROM
  material
      LEFT JOIN
  producao ON material.id_prod = producao.id_prod
WHERE
  producao.id_producao = '$id'
GROUP BY material.nome";

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $material = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
                    $qtd = $row['qtd'];                    
                    $qtdTotal = $row['total'];
                }           
}
?>
```

Quebrei ele para ficar melhor de entender o que está acontecendo, por favor teste e me diga se funcionou como gostaria.